# Bootstrap javascript data-attributes - how to rescan

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

(btw I'm using Bootstrap 2.3.2)

Bootstrap uses data attributes (eg `data-toggle="buttons-radio"`) to give a particular set of HTML some functionality without using JavaScript (see [here](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#overview)).

However, say I have a given page and using jQuery I stick a huge chunk of new HTML into it, and that HTML has these data attributes. Bootstrap doesn't register them.  I'm guessing that's because it does a single pass when the js is loaded and then doesn't know to look again when the DOM changes.

Is there a way to tell Bootstrap to check the page again and apply the logic to the new DOM elements?

Comment: Can you tell us which JavaScript plugins you need to reload exactly? Which data-attributes are you adding by using jQuery?

Comment: An example would be the bootstrap radio buttons (scroll down a bit from this link): http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#buttons

Comment: The reason why I wanted to know which JavaScript plugins of bootstrap you are using is because the reinitialization of each of them is different. therefore I wanted to know which of them you are using and how many different ones you are using. There is no JS method to reinitialize the javascript like you want to. there are hacks like removing the js-file from source and then reading it, but that is dirty and leads to problems. therefore please tell us which js plugins you need to reinitialize.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking to see if there was a more general way to init all bootstrap plugins, but, in the case of the radio buttons plugin, how would you do it?